# Destructure same variables from multiple objects

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, destructuring

I have 3 objects

```
 var first = {name:'ab', age:'12',year:'2010',color:'red'};
var second = {name:'ax', age:'14',year:'2011',mood:'sour'};
var third = {name:'ay', age:'15',year:'2012',dessert:'cake'};
```

I need to access the items within first, second and third, which I presently do via destructuring.

```
let {name, age, year, color} = a;
//perform some action here
let {name, age, year, mood} = b;
//perform some action here
let {name, age, year, dessert} = c;
//perform some action here.
```

Note: For this eg. I am only showing few items inside each object, in the real world case I have around 20+ with 15 of them repeating in all of them.

Since I have name, age and year repeating every time, is there a way to optimize the code that I can declare these 3 variables elsewhere and just mention that while destructuring.

For eg:

```
let commonVars = {name, age, year}
let {...commonvars, color} = a;
let {...commonvars, mood} = b;
let {...commonvars, dessert} = c;
```

Because I seem to keep repeating this over and over.

Comment: Why not use a function? `({name, age, year}) => { /* whatever */}`

Comment: No, there isn't. You can't re-let the same names anyway.

Comment: Why can't you use dot notation instead of creating new variables? `first.name`, `second.name`. Even this `first`/`fifteenth` seems to be wrong use

Comment: Why are you not using an array?

Comment: @VLAZ, these are multiple objects where about 15 of the variables repeat, while the rest are unique. So I cannot Assume that either. Let me update the question

Comment: @Justinas it is an example, not my actual code.

Comment: @adiga use an array how?

Comment: Create an array of the variables. `const array = [first, second, third]` and then you can get an array of names like: `const namesArray = array.map(o => o.name)`

Comment: @adiga I updated my question, I forgot to mention that other than those 3 variables there will be some more variables which will be unique to that object. Your suggestion might work though. I could try setting up ternary operators to see if those unique variables exist, and only then perform an operation on them. Let me give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: You can have a separate object like `let commonVars = {name, age, year}` and use `commonVars.name` instead of destructing and using just `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `updateCommonVars` function and have `commonVars` `object` which holds all common values. Use it as `updateCommonVars(first);` to copy `values` to `commonVars` object. And use `commonVars.name` etc.

```js
let updateCommonVars = (obj) => {
  for (prop in commonVars)
    commonVars[prop] = obj[prop];
}

var first = {name:'ab', age:'12',year:'2010',color:'red'};
var second = {name:'ax', age:'14',year:'2011',mood:'sour'};
var third = {name:'ay', age:'15',year:'2012',dessert:'cake'};

let commonVars = {name:null, age:null, year:null};

updateCommonVars(first);
let { color } = first;
console.log(commonVars.name);

updateCommonVars(second);
let { mood } = second;
console.log(commonVars.name);
```